# How to force Firefox to sync my bookmark just now?

Tags: firefox, sync

A few minutes before I leave my desk, and I have add a lot of new bookmarks. How to force Firefox to sync my bookmark right now to my firefox account ?

Comment: The accepted answers are no longer valid with Firefox 30...

Comment: Pressing [Alt] to bring up the menu and then going to *Tools → Sync Now* works for me in FireFox 30.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Firefox → Sync Now*, or if you have the menu bar enabled, *Tools → Sync Now*.

Comment: I found it myself... Soooo obvious :)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, nothing has changed much in the latest versions of Firefox except
the user interface :
One sets up the sync in menu "Tools → Options → Sync", then uses "Tools → Sync Now".

If you do not see the menu, right-click an empty space in the above panels
and click on "Menu Bar".

@Peltier:

If the problem is with the new panel that is opened by the Firefox button
missing the "Sync Now" icon,
click the Customize button in that panel, drag the "Sync" button on the left into the
panel, then close the customize tab.

You can now click on "Firefox → Sync" to sync now.

Comment: I agree this works but the menu bar is arguably a thing of the past. Is there really no way to do this within the new interface?

Comment: I described above how to, by customizing the panel that is opened by the Firefox button.

Comment: ...and the bounty is for you! (in 20 hours)

Comment: You can also drag the Sync button (from the Customisation screen) near the Awesome bar for easier access.

Comment: @DragoonHP: Correct, one can drag it to any panel at all, even downwards.

Answer (score 7):

Mouse users:
Strike an [Alt] key and the menu appears (Firefox 29) then > Tools > Sync Now

Keyboard users:
Alt+T > S

Answer (score 2):

For all versions of Firefox (including 30, the latest at the time of this post) you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then, when the menu appears at the top, select *Tools → Sync Now*.

In addition you can also reduce the sync duration:

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar, hit enter and confirm you'll be careful.
2. Search for `services.sync.syncInterval`
3. Change this value to any value **in milliseconds** you want. If you want every 15 minutes then you need to set this to `900000` (which is 15 x 60 x 1000).
4. Close and restart Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may just click on the firefox sync logo (to be found on the lower right in the status line)

Comment: Not present anymore in Firefox 6 and 7 (and neither, technically, is the status line).

Comment: yeap, same problem as grawity

Answer (score 1):

### Firefox 57 and later

In Firefox Quantum versions 57 and later follow [these steps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1214940):

1. Login to Firefox with your master password.
2. Click the 3 horizontal lines **≡** toolbar button (labeled **Open menu** on cursor hover) in the upper right corner of Firefox.
3. A dual-circular arrow appears to the right of that email address, which will "spin" when Firefox is communicating with the Sync server. That "dual-circular arrow " also serves as a button for doing a manual sync event; upon cursor hover that "button" will show the Day and Time of the last sync event, either automatic or manual.